# Unitary conjugation preserves product forms

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, tensor-products

I would like to know if, given a finite Hilbert space $H$, and two (unitary) linear operators
$A,B:H\to H$, 
$$ W^* (A\otimes B)W:H\otimes H\to H \otimes H $$
is also a product form operator, given any (unitary) linear $W:H\otimes H\to H\otimes H$. I would be very pleased for any hint. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

androidAssuming that by "product form operator" you mean "elementary tensor", the answer is no. Even in finite dimension. Projections of the same rank are unitarily equivalent, so the result would imply that all projections are given by elementary tensors.

Consider $H=\mathbb C^2$, $A=B=\begin{bmatrix} 1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$. Then $A\otimes B$ is the rank-one projection
$$
A\otimes B=\begin{bmatrix} 1&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}. 
$$
Another rank-one projection in $M_2(\mathbb C)\otimes M_2(\mathbb C)$ is 
$$
P=\begin{bmatrix} 1/2&0&0&1/2\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\\ 1/2&0&0&1/2\end{bmatrix},
$$
which is well-known not to be an elementary tensor. Being of the same rank, there exists a unitary $W$ such that $$W(A\otimes B)W^*=P.$$

The answer is the same when $A,B$ are unitary. For instance, again with $H=\mathbb C^2$ and using the usual representation of $A\otimes B$ as $\{A_{kj}B_{st}\}$ the unitary 
$$
U=\begin{bmatrix} 1/\sqrt2&0&0&1/\sqrt2\\ 0&1&0&0\\ 0&0&-1&0\\ 1/\sqrt2&0&0&-1/\sqrt2\end{bmatrix}
$$
is not an elementary tensor. If it were, we would have $A_{11}B_{11}=1/\sqrt2$, $A_{11}B_{12}=0$, $A_{12}B_{12}=1/\sqrt2$, which is impossible.

On the other hand, if $A=B=\begin{bmatrix} 0&i\\-i&0\end{bmatrix}$, then the eigenvalues of $A\otimes B$ are $1,1,-1,-1$. As $A\otimes B$ and $U$ have the same eigenvalues with the same multiplicities, there exists a unitary $W$ with $W(A\otimes B)W^*=U$.

Comment: Thanks! But $A$ and $B$ are not unitary... In the case of full-rank $A$ and $B$?

Comment: Of course they aren't. You edited the word "unitary" in, eight minutes after I answered.

Comment: it's my fault, I forgot it, every operator I am treating is unitary

Comment: Still it doesn't change the answer. I have edited an example in.

Comment: But the last matrix has eigenvalues $\{-1,1,1,1\}$ and any matrix $W^*(A\otimes B)W$ has the same eigenvalues as $A\otimes B$, which come in the form $\lambda_i\mu_j$, $i,j\in\{1,2\}$, where $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$ are the eigenvalues of $A$ and $\mu_1,\mu_2$ of $B$. If, for example, $\lambda_1\mu_1 = -1$, then $\lambda_2\mu_1 = \lambda_2\mu_2 = 1$ which implies that $\mu_1 = \mu_2 = 1$, and hence $\lambda_1\mu_2 = -1$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: You are totally right. I have edited the example.

Comment: I think that $i$'s in $U$ should be replaced by $1$'s in order to have the same eigenvalues, but you are correct. Thank you for this clarifying example.

Comment: My bad, I thought I had changed them.